# Grails Query, How to get a specific field in the result?

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-orm

I have the domain class:

```
class Product {

    String barcode
    String name
    String measurement

    static constraints = {

    }
}
```

Now, I want to get a list with only one field like "name":

> Product.findAllByNameIlike("%$params.name%",[order: "desc" ])

Comment: and what is the question?  do you get an error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Product.findAllByNameIlike("%$params.name%",[order: "desc" ])?.collect{it.name}
```

Comment: `Product.findAllByNameIlike("%$params.name%",[order: "desc" ])?.name`

Comment: This query returns full table data and generates full instances, then on memory extracts one value. A better approach is to use projections on a criteria to return just one column from the database.

Comment: is it possible to collect multiple fields with same approach?